# Render from another controller method

Tags: laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.5 version and I have a question.

Let's say that my controller has 2 methods like this:

```
public function errorsCheck(){
    return view('errors_check');
}

public function index(){
     $this->errorsCheck();
     // some other important code
}
```

And when I open my webpage it goes to index() method first. Then it calls errorsCheck(). And errorsCheck() has to render view file and stop script executing.

How can I do it? I can't make something like:

```
return $this->errorsCheck();
```

because I need code above to execute if errorsCheck method doesnt found any errors. And this is not validation errors, btw.

Any ideas? Thanks.

**SOLUTION:**

Well, solution is:

```
throw new HttpResponseException(
    Response::view('account.denied.not_active_account')
);
```

It will throw exception, but Laravel catch it and will render view.

Comment: So, you want to check for errors in a view before it is rendered? And when it found errors it should stop rendering the view, and render a view with errors?

Comment: No, why? I'm checking errors in controller. But not in method that executing by route rule. It should be like laravel validator.

Comment: I don't really understand your question then, sorry.
Let's walk through it again.

You open your webpage, ( Any webpage of your project or just a specific one?) And it will call the `index()` method, which calls the method `errorsCheck()`, Which, should render a view and `exit;` or `die` when it finds errors ( What kind of errors? )? and if it doens't find any errors continue doing what ever it's doing?

Comment: If the above is what should be happening, try this:
`$view = \View::make('errors_check');` `$render = $view->render();` in the `errorCheck();` method

Comment: It will not render view, just write html to $render.

Answer (score 0):

Well, solution is:

```
throw new HttpResponseException(
    Response::view('account.denied.not_active_account')
);
```

It will throw exception, but Laravel catch it and will render view.